# Use MinGW to compile x264 in windows, Error Code 5

Tags: mingw, x264

```
rm -f libx264.a    
gcc-ar rc libx264.a  common/osdep.o common/base.o common/cpu.o common/tables.o encoder/api.o common/win32thread.o common/mc-8.o common/predict-8.o common/pixel-8.o common/macroblock-8.o common/frame-8.o common/dct-8.o common/cabac-8.o common/common-8.o common/rectangle-8.o common/set-8.o common/quant-8.o common/deblock-8.o common/vlc-8.o common/mvpred-8.o common/bitstream-8.o encoder/analyse-8.o encoder/me-8.o encoder/ratecontrol-8.o encoder/set-8.o encoder/macroblock-8.o encoder/cabac-8.o encoder/cavlc-8.o encoder/encoder-8.o encoder/lookahead-8.o common/threadpool-8.o common/x86/mc-c-8.o common/x86/predict-c-8.o common/opencl-8.o encoder/slicetype-cl-8.o common/mc-10.o common/predict-10.o common/pixel-10.o common/macroblock-10.o common/frame-10.o common/dct-10.o common/cabac-10.o common/common-10.o common/rectangle-10.o common/set-10.o common/quant-10.o common/deblock-10.o common/vlc-10.o common/mvpred-10.o common/bitstream-10.o encoder/analyse-10.o encoder/me-10.o encoder/ratecontrol-10.o encoder/set-10.o encoder/macroblock-10.o encoder/cabac-10.o encoder/cavlc-10.o encoder/encoder-10.o encoder/lookahead-10.o common/threadpool-10.o common/x86/mc-c-10.o common/x86/predict-c-10.o  common/x86/cpu-a.o common/x86/dct-32-8.o common/x86/pixel-32-8.o common/x86/bitstream-a-8.o common/x86/const-a-8.o common/x86/cabac-a-8.o common/x86/dct-a-8.o common/x86/deblock-a-8.o common/x86/mc-a-8.o common/x86/mc-a2-8.o common/x86/pixel-a-8.o common/x86/predict-a-8.o common/x86/quant-a-8.o common/x86/sad-a-8.o common/x86/dct-32-10.o common/x86/pixel-32-10.o common/x86/bitstream-a-10.o common/x86/const-a-10.o common/x86/cabac-a-10.o common/x86/dct-a-10.o common/x86/deblock-a-10.o common/x86/mc-a-10.o common/x86/mc-a2-10.o common/x86/pixel-a-10.o common/x86/predict-a-10.o common/x86/quant-a-10.o common/x86/sad16-a-10.o
make: *** [libx264.a] Error 5
```

The text above is the output infomation in the shell, and I don't know how to get more detailed information.
What does "Error 5" means?

Comment: I just input command ./configure & make

Comment: I reinstall my MinGW and try it again, and finally success. OMG!